# Subplot shown in lower right figure corner instead of inside the grid

Tags: python, matplotlib

Here is a reproducible code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
data_list = [np.random.normal(0, 1, [10]) for i in range(50)]
data_it = iter(data_list)

fig_size = (12, 8)
num_subs = 30
num_imgs = len(data_list)
num_figs = num_imgs/num_subs + 1

fig_list = []
for i in xrange(num_figs):
    fig = plt.figure(i, figsize=fig_size)
    fig_list.append(fig)
    for j in range(num_subs):
        ax = fig.add_subplot(5, 6, j)
        ax.tick_params(bottom='off', top='off', left='off', right='off',
                       labelbottom='off', labeltop='off', labelright='off', labelleft='off')
        ax.plot(np.arange(10), data_it.next())
        ax.set_title('look at this!')
```

[image]

But as you can see above, I have a lonely subplot all the way at the right end corner of my figure 1. I can't find the error which is causing this to happen. Could someone please point out what I must fix in order for the figure1 to have nicely ordered subplots? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Oh I found out the problem:

the index of the subplots must start with 1. If you have 0, this will make the figure draw a subplot at the right end corner of the figure.

In other words, just adding 1 to the j at the for loop will fix the problem

Thanks anyhow!